# How to fire click event using cards?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm working with 2 panels using cards. If I click on **"Go to first"** it takes me to First Panel and if I click on **"Go to second"** it takes me to the Second Panel. This works great!

- The issue is that, I want to fire a click event without using the `handler` that is already on the **"Go to first"** `button`. In simple words, I want to be able to fire click event to execute my **sendMessage** function. So if I'm on Second Panel and click on **"Go to first"** I want to update the text that is inside First Panel to say:

> "This is the first panel message-recieved"

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing in my code? So far I'm firing the click event inside the **boxready** event, but it will only get called once page loads and after that I cannot call **sendMessage** anymore.

**Code snippet:**

```
listeners: {
    boxready: function (cmp) {
        cmp.down('[name=someButton]').fireEvent('click', me.sendMessage());
    }
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/d68qre4w/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [`card`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.layout.container.Card.html) layout so you need to use [`activate`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html#event-activate) event for child component of `card` panel.

- **activate**

  Fires after a Component has been visually activated.

  **Note** This event is only fired if this Component is a child of a [`Ext.container.Container`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.container.Container.html) that uses [`Ext.layout.container.Card`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html#event-activate) as it's layout or this Component is a floating Component.

In this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2i4d), I have used your code and put modification with `activate` event on child components.

Code snippet:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.application({
            name: 'Fiddle',

            launch: function () {
                var me = this,
                    sendMessage = function (msg) {
                        alert('message-recieved from : ' + msg);
                    };

                Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    height: 400,
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    title: 'Card Layout Example',
                    layout: 'card',
                    defaults: {
                        listeners: {
                            activate: function (panel) {
                                sendMessage(panel.msg);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'First',
                        msg: 'This Panel one activated',
                        html: 'This is the first panel'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Second',
                        msg: 'This Panel two activated',
                        html: 'This is the second panel'
                    }],
                    dockedItems: [{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'bottom',
                        items: [{
                            text: '<- Go to first',
                            name: 'someButton',
                            handler: function (button) {
                                var panel = button.up('panel');
                                panel.layout.setActiveItem(0);
                            }
                        }, '->', {
                            text: 'Go to second ->',
                            handler: function (button) {
                                var panel = button.up('panel');
                                panel.layout.setActiveItem(1);
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `listeners` in `panel` instead of box.

**You can see here:** [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Chintan_hotmail/v3z5t0s1/)

**Code snippet:**

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'First',
    html: 'This is the first panel',
    listeners: {
        show: function () {
            me.sendMessage(this.initialConfig.html);
        },
        render: function () {
            me.sendMessage(this.initialConfig.html);
        }
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Second',
    html: 'This is the second panel'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2i4c).

**Code snippet:**

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'First',
    itemId: 'firstPanel',
    html: 'This is the first panel',
    listeners: {
        activate: function (cmp) {
            cmp.up('panel').down('[name=someButton]').fireEvent('click', me.sendMessage());
        }
    }
}
```